# Undertow Simple HelloWorld not working on Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, httplistener, undertow

Im creating a simple undertow HTTP server following the documentation:
http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/index.html

```
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
         .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
         .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
               exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
               exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
            }
         }).build();
      server.start();
   }
```

It works normally on localhost. But when I deploy on Cloud Foundry as a standalone java app:

```
cf push im-gateway -p target\gateway.jar
```

The app fails to start and show this error in the log:

```
Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

After investigation, I modify the push command:

```
cf push im-gateway -p target\gateway.jar --no-route
```

The deployment this time is successful, i create the route manually and try to access it but got the error:

```
502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.
```

Which port should I listen on ? How Cloud Foundry redirect the request to my app ?

I appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs Cloud Foundry dynamically assigns a port to each app instance.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#PORT

Try replacing `.addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")` with `.addHttpListener(System.getenv("PORT"), "0.0.0.0")`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Small fix: Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"))